# Problem with JW Player

Tags: video

How to prevent JW Player from showing things like "Like this video? Share it!" and also remove the label that says jwplayer?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a simpler way than what Henri suggested then [buy it](https://www.longtailvideo.com/players/order) :)

Comment: I knew there was a page to buy a license!
I just couldn't find it :/

Answer (score 3):

To remove the "jwplayer" and the "Like this video?" labels download the [source code](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/tags/mediaplayer-4.4) and remove them from there, then compile the fla and upload it to your server.

Comment: Don't think it is, I only suggested this because I couldn't find the order page.
It should be legal for the "Like this video?" label though.

Answer (score 2):

When you [download JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/),
make sure you uncheck **Include Viral, a video sharing plugin**